# Emulating xbox controller output from pc to console

Tags: usb, xbox

Is there a way to emulate an xbox controller by sending a custom signal or cloning the protocol with a usb dongle? I want to use a source from a PC as a controller for an xbox console.

Comment: I don't think you will find many people here willing to help you bot video games

Answer (score 3):

There's a work around solution to your problem. The Xbox app for Windows allows you to play games via streaming over a local network. The quality is imperfect, but if you have access to the console's actual video output you can set the stream quality to the lowest setting to minimize latency.

Streaming via the Xbox app for Windows will allow you to emulate a controller via any of a number of methods that convert various signals to X-input. I personally have tested this with a Dual Shock 4 controller and InputMapper. For your purposes, you may want to try EventGhost.

People shouldn't just throw shade automatically because you're designing a bot. There are plenty of respectable reasons for doing so, particularly academic ones. I hope you're not just trying to cheat, but if you are, it's an impressive way of going about it, at least.

Answer (score 2):

No, xbox controller wireless protocol is proprietary and nobody reverse-engineered it yet AFAIK.

To use a real xbox wireless controller on a PC (the opposite of what you want) you need an adapter, which is sold separately, and most USB XBOX code we have published is dedicated to make those adapters work on linux. The actual protocol of wireless communication between the adapter and the controller is a mystery. It is not normal wifi so you can't use any wifi adapter available in the market to mimic it.

Another option is to crack open an xbox controller and connect the components (using arduino maybe?) directly to the PC.